# Why does system("cls") not work correctly in Python as writing some weird arrow character?

Tags: python, cmd, character

So I have an odd bug which instead of making console clear writes that character.
That issue doesn't occur in **C**, and everything works normally when I write `cls` in command prompt window. (I am not an advanced programmer, but I suppose that `system()` is related with it.)

**Edit:** (When I use `clear`, it does completely nothing.) Perhaps that problem is not related to wrong keyword (I use Windows), it just didn't do what I was expecting because of drawing that weird arrow character.

**Edit2:** I reinstalled whole vs with phyton, and it doesn't worked

**Edit3:** resolved : ["Windows Command Prompt shortcut doesn't work correctly (Ctrl + L)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270264/windows-command-prompt-shortcut-doesnt-work-correctly-ctrl-l?noredirect=1#comment113650176_64270264)

[image: [image]]

```
from os import system

while True :
    print(" #")
    system("cls")
```

Comment: Is there some redirection/piping involved in your code? As far as I remember, the DOS/Windows `cls` command just sends the form-feed character (FF, `0x0C`) to the console, which might become translated into something else in case…

Answer (score 1):

try this function to clear the screen regardless of OS

```
from os import system, name 
def clear(): 
    if name == 'nt': 
        x = system('cls') 
    else: 
        x = system('clear')
```

or you could try using subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call 
  
def clear(): 
    x = call('clear' if os.name =='posix' else 'cls')
```

Other than that I think it would be some problem with your terminal

Comment: it doesn't work, now I explained more in description

Comment: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: in that case, I have no idea, both of the above work for me, maybe try reinstalling, or try toying with the escape characters, this question shouldn't have been closed.